# Implementing Server-Sent-Events through Apigee proxy

Tags: proxy, server-sent-events, apigee

I have a project which utilizes server-sent-events to send progress update data to the front-end through an Apigee proxy. I've done some research and found very few posts about it, including one that said Apigee does not support server-sent-events. I wanted to know what are the limitations that Apigee has that won't allow this type of communication and i there's any way to bypass it.

I still haven't implemented it but wanted to understand what could cause an issue when trying to use server-sent-events with Apigee and if there are any ideas to avoid these issues.